# Determining covariance by multiple grouping variables in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to calculate the covariance (or correlation) between the average stem counts of two species. The stem count value averages are in the "avg" column and the species are listed together in the column "Spnum", and they are assigned ID's of 2 and 18. I would like to split out these calculations by Year, Season, and Treatment.

I believe I am getting close using ddply, but I am stuck figuring out how to tell ddply that the values are in a separate column ("avg") than the species that were measured.

```
row.namesYear Spnum     avg     Season  Treatment
1   1   2005    2       21.8    early   delay
2   7   2005    18      18.5    early   delay
3   31  2005    2       24.5    early   delay
4   37  2005    18      13.2    early   delay
5   60  2005    2       20.7    early   ambi
6   66  2005    18      31.0    early   ambi
7   89  2005    2       36.5    early   ambi
...
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: cv<-ddply(rstem.asl,c("Year", "Season", "Treatment", "Spnum"),function(x) cor(x$Spnum==2,x$Spnum==18))

Comment: I posted two options using dplyr and data.table.  Please check if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options using `dplyr` and `data.table`.  We group by 'Year', 'Season', 'Treatment' variables and then get the `cor` of 'avg' that corresponds to 'Spnum' value of 2 againsg the 'Spnum' value of 18 (`avg[Spnum==18]`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Year, Season, Treatment) %>%
  summarise(Cor= cor(avg[Spnum==2], avg[Spnum==18]))
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`). grouped by the variables (as described above), we get the `cor`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Cor= cor(avg[Spnum==2], avg[Spnum==18])), by =.(Year, Season, Treatment)]
```